# Understanding covariance in my Scala code

Tags: scala, apache-spark, covariance, contravariance

I am working through the correct syntax and structure for the following problem.

I have two datasets with two separate schemas--call them `ClientEvent` and `ServerEvent`--stored on disk. The codebase I am working on has defined a class, `Reader[T :< Asset]` where `ClientEvent` and `ServerEvent` are subtypes of `Asset`. `Asset` is a trait.

I am writing a function:

```
def getPathAndReader(config): (String, Reader[Asset]) = {
    if (config.readClient) {
        return getClientPathAndReader(config)
    } else {
        return getServerPathAndReader(config)
    } 
}
```

This does not compile in my Scala code. From my understanding, `T` must be a subtype of `Asset`, which both `ServerEvent` and `ClientEvent` are, therefore `Reader[ServerEvent] <: Reader[Asset]`. But since functions are covariant in their inputs, the function I wrote cannot just return this lower type, I'd have to cast it to a supertype? Does that lose too much information?

`load` is a function on the trait `Asset`

```
trait Reader[T <: Asset] {
  def load(raw: DataFrame): Dataset[T]
}
```

What would be an alternative way to structure this code?

The code's intent is to take the file path returned, and call `Reader::load(filePath: String)` to get data back. The subtyped readers have some internal logic to clean the data that it retrieves from disk before it's returned as a `Dataframe`. This means it relies on the type that it passes in. I come from a C++/C# background so my thinking is that if you have a generic `Reader[Asset]` but call `Reader::load(path: String)` it will know what to do based on the type it actually is, similar to `Base* ptr` and calling a derived method.

Comment: Just a hint: since you said you are familiar with C♯, I wanted to point out that variance in Scala is more or less exactly like in C♯, namely declaration-site variance with mostly explicit annotations and some inference. This is very much unlike Java's use-site variance.

Answer (score 2):

Your claim that
*"From my understanding, `T` must be a subtype of `Asset`, which both `ServerEvent` and `ClientEvent` are, therefore `Reader[ServerEvent] <: Reader[Asset]`."* is not correct. Generally if `A` and `B` are usual types such as `A <: B` and `G[T]` is a generic type, then all 3 cases are possible:

- Co-variant case `G[A] <: G[B]` - typical example is some read-only collection like `Iterator`
- Contra-variant case `G[A] :> G[B]` - typical example is some kind of a consumer like a function `T => ()`
- Invariant case where `G[A]` and `G[B]` are not related. The most typical case when some uses of the `T` are co-variant and some a contravariant. For example, a simple mapping function `T => T` is invariant. Also most of the mutable collections are invariant as well because the both "produce" and "consume" objects.

Unfortunately for you `Dataset[T]` is invariant (rather than covariant `Dataset[+T]` or contravariant `Dataset[-T]`).  This effectively makes your `Reader` also invariant. As to how to work this around, it is hard to advice without understanding a larger context. For example, why your `getClientPathAndReader` and `getServerPathAndReader` do not return `Dataset[Asset]`? If you really then use specific `ServerEvent` and `ClientEvent`, then your design is not type-safe anyway. If you use only `Asset`, then changing your readers to return `Dataset[Asset]` seems the easiest solution.